# Double while loop with MYSQL return

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL double while loop in php:

```
$geta=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id<50");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($geta)){
while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($geta)){
$id1=$row['id'];
$id2=$row2['id'];
echo "$id1 and $id2";
}
}
```

I'm trying to make every possible combination of id with another id.

Not sure what is wrong with it...output is just a list of id1...

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you call `mysql_fetch_array()`, you fetch the next result from the same result set from the MySQL database. So calling it twice in an outer and inner loop just advances the record pointer.

In your case, you should load all results to a single array first, then iterate over that:

```
// Array to hold all results
$results = array();
$geta = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id<50");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($geta)){
  // Append all rows to the array
  $results[] = $row;
}

// Now iterate over your array $results in the outer & inner loops
foreach ($results as $r1) {
  foreach ($results as $r2) {
    echo "$r1  and $r2";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can even use a simple cross join

```
select t1.id,t2.id 
from table as t1
cross join table as t2 on t1.id <= 50 and t2.id <= 50
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$geta = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id<50");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($geta)) {
   $all_ids = $row['id'];
}

foreach ($all_ids as $id_a) {
  foreach ($all_ids as $id_b) {
    echo "$id_a and $id_b", "<br>\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

write one SQL statement that does the work...  This will be faster than doing 2 loops; allows the database to do all the heavy lifting, and you simply have to process the results!

```
SELECT A.id, B.ID 
FROM table1 A 
cross join table1 B 
 WHERE A.id<50
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```
$geta=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id<50");
$getb=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id<50");
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($geta)){
    while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($getb)){
      $id1=$row['id'];
      $id2=$row2['id'];
      echo "$id1 and $id2";
    }
  }
```

or use a cross join

```
$getab=mysql_query("SELECT a.id as aid, b.id as bid FROM table1 a CROSS JOIN table1 b ON a.id = b.id WHERE a.id<50 AND b.id < 50");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($getab)){
  echo $row['aid'] . ' and ' . $row['bid'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That you are doing makes no sense. `mysql_fetch_*` functions advance one by one through the result set. In your code the outer loop executes once with the first row, then the inner loop executes until you are out of rows.

You should do a cross join in SQL instead:

```
SELECT t1a.id AS id1, t1b.id AS id2 FROM table1 t1a, table1 t1b WHERE t1a.id<50 AND t1b.id<50
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pretty straight forward :

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($geta)){
```

This while statements fetches the first row from result object $geta. and

```
while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($geta)){
```

This loop fetches the remaining rows from the result object $geta

Then finaly after second loop when it goes back to the first loop , all the rows have been fetched already , and hence condition in loop fails (because no more rows to fetch) and hence loop exits . in effect you get the list of ids .

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array increases the internal seek pointer of the same result set $geta. So it's not working. If you just make a copy the $geta variable and use it instead, it will work.

```
$geta=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id<50");
$geta2=$geta;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($geta))
{
    while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($geta2))
    {
      $id1=$row['id'];
      $id2=$row2['id'];
      echo "$id1 and $id2";
    }
}
```