# How to group cells together in columns, in PHP

Tags: php, css, html

I have written code in PHP (listed below,) but face a small problem...

```
<html>
<head>
<title> trans </title>
<body>
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 700px;
margin: auto;
}
</style>
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if(!$con)
{
    die("not ok");
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"uoh");  


$q1 = "SELECT * FROM student_record INNER JOIN degree_plan ON
 student_record.course_number = degree_plan.course_number 
 INNER JOIN courses ON student_record.course_number = 
 courses.course_number where student_record.id  = 201102887 AND degree_plan.major='COE'";

$result = mysqli_query($con , $q1 ) ;
if($result){
   echo "<table>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<th>courses</th>";
   echo "<th>terms</th>";
   echo "<th>grades</th>";
   echo "<th>CRD</th>";
   echo "</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row["code"]. "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row["term_no"]. "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row["grade"]. "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
   }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the code I see the following output:

```
---------------------------------------
|   courses    |   terms  |   grades  |
---------------------------------------
|   CHEM 101   |     1    |     A     |
---------------------------------------
|   ENGL 101   |     1    |     C+    |
---------------------------------------
|   PE 101     |     1    |     B     |
---------------------------------------
|   PHYS 101   |     1    |     F     |
---------------------------------------
|   ENGL 102   |     2    |     B+    |
---------------------------------------
|   PE 101     |     2    |     B     |
---------------------------------------
|   PHYS 102   |     2    |     D+    |
---------------------------------------
|   MATH 201   |     3    |     A     |
---------------------------------------
|   COE 200    |     3    |     B     |
---------------------------------------
```

But I do not want it like that. I want the term cells to become one, like this:

```
---------------------------------------
|   courses    |   term   |   grade   |
---------------------------------------
|   CHEM 101         1          A     |
|   ENGL 101                    C+    |
|   PE 101                      B     |
|   PHYS 101                    F     |
---------------------------------------
|   ENGL 102         2          B+    |
|   PE 101                      B     |
|   PHYS 102                    D+    |
---------------------------------------
|   MATH 201         3          A     |
|   COE 200                     B     |
---------------------------------------
```

or in any other way that does not let term repeat, by which I mean: group the courses that have the same term together.

Comment: Although marked as bad practice you could do what is done here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778012/double-while-loop-with-mysql-return. Use the `while` loop to collect all rows, then use `foreach` to iterate over them and output an empty `td`tag in case the term is the same as the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code,

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $data[$row["term_no"]][] =  array(
        'code' => $row["code"],
        'grade' => $row["grade"]
    );

}


echo '<table width="200" border="1">';
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<th>courses</th>";
   echo "<th>terms</th>";
   echo "<th>grades</th>";
   echo "</tr>";

foreach($data as $term=>$otherrow) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($otherrow as $data) {
        if($count == 0) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $data["code"]. "</td>";
            echo '<td rowspan="'.count($otherrow).'">' . $term. '</td>';
            echo "<td>" . $data["grade"]. "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }else {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $data["code"]. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $data["grade"]. "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        $count++;
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```